# NHibernate, SQLite, and Cyrillic characters: case sensitivity and fallback queries

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, character-encoding, internationalization

I'm querying an SQLite database using NHibernate. Generally, I want to do case insensitive string queries. Recently, I've discovered that although I can insert a row with Cyrillic characters, I can not select it using a case insensitive query. This is what the query looks like:

```
string foo = "foo";
IList<T> list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).
    Add(Expression.Eq("Foo", foo).IgnoreCase()).List<T>();
```

I can, however, select the row using the above query if IgnoreCase() is removed. A naive fix would be to check if list.Count == 0 after the first query, and make a subsequent case sensitive query. The major downside of this approach is that querying for non-existent rows is a reasonably common operation that would now consist of two queries.

The question is, how can I construct a **single** query that will select from the Foo column that is case insensitive yet will also select rows that contain Cyrillic characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case insensitive queries by default only work with ASCII characters in SQLite.

See this FAQ: [Case-insensitive matching of Unicode characters does not work.](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q18)

Comment: Thanks. This describes why it isn't working. It does not describe a potential fix or workaround. Even building with ICU support does not seem to have a general case fix, from what I've been able to find.

Comment: For the LIKE operator, SQLite's ICU extension makes use of language independent case folding, AFAIK. Perhaps some of the examples given here might be helpful: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/fileview?f=sqlite/ext/icu/README.txt